# when several lists add together, finallist[1][1] cannot replace only one element

Tags: python, python-3.x

The question is:

```
a = [['0','0','0']]
b = [ ]
b = b + a + a
print(b)
```

output is

```
[['0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0']]
```

however when I type

```
b[0][0] = 'x'
print(b)
```

the output is

```
[['x', '0', '0'], ['x', '0', '0']]
```

I am wonder how to replace only the first element in `b`, like

```
[['x', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0']]
```

Comment: you can use copy.copy to make a copy of the object instead of the reference. b gets two references to the same object (the original a). So any operation to one affects the other one.

Comment: This video explains the problem you are seeing quite well: https://youtu.be/sH4XF6pKKmk?t=8m14s

Answer (score 1):

When you are concatenating a with a and storing in b, you are just concatenating the reference to the same list (inner list in this case) twice, you are not copying the inner list. That is why any changes inside `b[0]` reflects inside `b[1]` . You can try copying the list like -

```
import copy
b = b + copy.deepcopy(a) + copy.deepcopy(a)
```

`copy.deepcopy()` does deep copying, which is what you want.